# when a child process is created using fork() system call, where the child process starts execution?

Tags: c, operating-system, multiprocessing, fork

The problem is that, I have read that the child process will start execution after the fork() system call but then here I must get "This is for sure Parent" only once if the child starts from fork() but as the output shows, it's printing twice.

```
#include  <stdio.h> 

int main(void)
{
  printf("This is for sure parent\n");
  fork();
  printf("This maybe child or parent\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the Output:

```
This is for sure parent
This maybe child or parent
This is for sure parent
This maybe child or parent
```

Comment: do not believe printf

Comment: That's because without flushing both processes get their copy of stdio buffer.

Comment: fflush(stdout) before fork()

Comment: Does the buffer need to be flushed if the printf ends with a newline character?

Comment: no becuase stdout is line buffered @ChristianGibbons